# parse JSON out from curl response using Sed or awk and assign to variable for later use

Tags: linux, unix, curl, awk, sed

I am writing a bash script to be run on a linux appliance so I do not have access to install jq, I need to be able to use native Linux tools

```
curl --location --request POST "https://api-mp.meraki.com/api/v1/networks/12345/switch/stacks/12345/routing/interfaces" \
  --header "X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key: 123key" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
    "name": "L3 int",
    "subnet": "192.168.249.0/24",
    "interfaceIp": "192.168.249.2",
    "multicastRouting": "disabled",
    "vlanId": 140,
    "ospfSettings": {
        "area": "0",
        "cost": 1,
        "isPassiveEnabled": true
    }
}'  | sed -n 's|.*"interfaceID":"\([^"]*\)".*|\1|p' > $newVar
```

the response from the server returns this:

```
{
"interfaceId": "12345",
"name": "PA L3 DR Int",
"subnet": "192.168.249.0/24",
"interfaceIp": "192.168.249.2",
"multicastRouting": "disabled",
"vlanId": 140,
"ospfSettings": {
    "area": "0",
    "cost": 1,
    "isPassiveEnabled": true
}
}
```

I then need to be able to access the interfaceID new variable in a query string paramter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just got the case wrong (`ID` vs `Id` in `interfaceId`) and forgot about the space after `:`, but you were close:

```
$ sed -n 's|.*"interfaceId": *"\([^"]*\)".*|\1|p' file
12345
```

Using `cat file` in place of your `curl` command to show how to save that to a variable in case you don't know:

```
$ var=$(cat file | sed -n 's|.*"interfaceId": *"\([^"]*\)".*|\1|p')
$ echo "$var"
12345
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. Tested successfully in link
https://ideone.com/EsdCQp

```
your_command | 
awk '
/"interfaceId": "/{
  gsub(/[^0-9]+|"\,/,"")
  print
}
'
```